# IntelliJ - Space after comma is replaced when entering a decimal value

Tags: intellij-idea

I am typing in the arguments for a function, and it is really annoying when IntelliJ removes the space after a comma, when entering a decimal.

Expected:

```
someFunction(true, .1);
```

Actual:

```
someFunction(true,.1);
```

The instant I press the "." key, the previous space is removed. This doesn't make any sense to me. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with your code style for the given language.

[Configuring Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-code-style.html)

Hopefully that pushes you in the right direction.